# Attempt to compare nil with number on (i).x < 100 then

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to spawn a new display.newRect if to old one is < 100 but I'm getting a  'Attempt to compare nil with number'

```
function hollSpawne(i)
    if (i).x < 100 then
         hollspawn()
    end
end
HollControll = timer.performWithDelay(  1400 , hollSpawne, 0 )
```

I cant see the error, could someone please explain how to fix this ?

Fullcode :

```
 function pluspoint(i)
 score = score + 1
 display.remove(i)
 end

 screenGroup = self.view
 holl = {}
 hollSpawn = function()

    i = display.newRect( 0, 0, math.random(10, 500), 53 )
    i.x = display.contentWidth + i.contentWidth + 10
    i.y = display.contentHeight - 53/2
    i:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
    i.name = "hollgameover"
    physics.addBody(i, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.5, friction=.2,filter=playerCollisionFilter } )      
    trans55 = transition.to(i,{time=2000, x=display.contentWidth - display.contentWidth - i.contentWidth/2 - 20, onComplete=pluspoint, transition=easing.OutExpo } )
    holl[#holl+1] = i
    screenGroup:insert(i)
end 
timereholl = timer.performWithDelay(  100 , hollSpawn, 1 )

function hollSpawne(i)
    if (i).x < 100 then
         hollspawn()
    end
end
HollControll = timer.performWithDelay(  1400 , hollSpawne, 0 )
```

### -

### -

new test still not working

```
 screenGroup = self.view
 holl = {}
 hollSpawn = function()

    i = display.newRect( 0, 0, math.random(10, 500), 53 )
    i.x = display.contentWidth + i.contentWidth + 10
    i.y = display.contentHeight - 53/2
    i:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
    i.name = "hollgameover"
    physics.addBody(i, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.5, friction=.2,filter=playerCollisionFilter } )      
    trans55 = transition.to(i,{time=2000, x=display.contentWidth - display.contentWidth - i.contentWidth/2 - 20, onComplete=pluspoint, transition=easing.OutExpo } )
    holl[#holl+1] = i
    screenGroup:insert(i)

end 
timereholl = timer.performWithDelay(  100 , hollSpawn, 1 )

function hollSpawne(event)
    if (i).x < 100 then
         hollSpawn()
    end
end
HollControll = timer.performWithDelay( 1400 , hollSpawne, 0 )
```

Comment: where else may I tell you to replace the "(i)" with just "i" in hollSpawne?

Answer (score 0):

Your timer calls hollSpawne with no arguments, but in function you use 'i' parameter.
Try this one:

```
local function hollSpawne(i)
    if i.x < 100 then
         hollspawn()
    end
end
HollControll = timer.performWithDelay(  1400 , function()
    hollSpawne(my_i_value)
end, 0 )
```

Comment: oky that calls the "hollSpawne(my_i_value)" but this part is still not woking "if (i).x < 100 then hollSpawn() end"

Answer (score 0):

The timer calls the listener with event as argument so i is an event. Since i is a global you can just have the arg be event:

```
function hollSpawne(event)
    if (i).x < 100 then
         hollSpawn()
    end
end
```

Note that I use `hollSpawn` not `hollspawn` as I think this is a typo that will cause additional bug.

Sidenote on style: not sure why you need `()` around `i`, un-Lua'ish. Also you probably should declare `i` local to your module:

```
local i

screenGroup = self.view
holl = {}
hollSpawn = function()
    i = display.newRect( 0, 0, math.random(10, 500), 53 )
    ...
```

Comment: the error is not oping up anymore but its not doing the "hollspawn()"

Comment: i added some code to my original question, but still it is not working